# custom widget triggers another custom widget's on_touch_down event

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Whenever I press any area in `MyWidget` then it trigger the first `MyButton` 's on_touch_down event inside `MyLayout` class.
I am new to kivy and don't understand why this is happening.

```
<MyButton@Button>:
  background_normal: ''
  background_color: [1,0,1,1]
  font_size: "44dp"
  color:[1,1,0,1]
  border:(1,1,1,1)
  text_size:self.size

<MyWidget@Widget>:
  id:customwidget
  canvas.before:
    Color:
      rgba:0.2,0.44,0.66,1
    Rectangle:
      pos:self.pos
      size:self.size

<MyLayout>:
  MyWidget:
    id:mywidget

  MyButton:
    id:button1
    text: "User Name"
    spacing: "10dp"
    on_touch_down: button1.text= self.text + "?"
    opacity: .8

  MyButton:
    text: "ikinci"
    on_touch_down: root.export_to_png("filename.png")
  MyButton:
    text: "ucuncu"
```

And this is python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class KivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python code

1. Create a `class MyButton()` and implement `on_touch_down()` method to check for collision of the touch with our widget.

### Snippet - Python code

```
class MyButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("\tMyButton.on_touch_down:")
            if self.text == 'User Name':
                self.text= self.text + "?"
            elif self.text == 'ikinci':
                App.get_running_app().root.export_to_png("filename.png")
            return True
        return super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

## kv file

1. Rename dynamic class `<MyButton@Button>:` to classs rule, `<MyButton>:`
2. Remove all `on_touch_down:` from `MyButton:`

### Snippet - kv file

```
<MyButton>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: [1,0,1,1]
    font_size: "44dp"
    color:[1,1,0,1]
    border:(1,1,1,1)
    text_size:self.size
...
    MyButton:
        id:button1
        text: "User Name"
        spacing: "10dp"
        opacity: .8

    MyButton:
        text: "ikinci"

    MyButton:
        text: "ucuncu"
```

[Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Clicked Button-User Name]
[image: Img02 - Clicked Button-ikinci]

Comment: thanks for answer but this runs button1 only one time, can I use id for comparison ?

Comment: You cannot use `ids` for comparison because its value is only valid in `kv file` and in dictionary type, `self.ids['button1']` or 'self.ids.button1`.

Answer (score 0):

The `on_touch` events are not specific to any widget, but are propagated to all your widgets. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=on_touch_down#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.on_touch_down). If you only want your `Button` to respond, you probably want to use `on_press`or `on_release` events instead (See [button behavior](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.button.ButtonBehavior)).